# How would I draw a hexagon made up of 6 triangles using GDImage?

Tags: c, drawing

I have to draw a lot of shapes for university using gdImage and have been supplied with some basic code, would anyone be able to explain how to fit in a hexagon made up of 6 triangles into this existing code? Using gdImage in C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gd.h>

int main()
{

  gdImagePtr gdImage = gdImageCreate( 480, 480); 
  FILE *jpgFile = NULL;
  int blue;
  gdImageColorAllocate( gdImage, 255, 255, 255 ); /* Uses the RGB values for white color. */
  blue = gdImageColorAllocate( gdImage, 110, 250, 250 ); /* Uses the RGB values for blue color. */


  gdImageSetThickness( gdImage, 4 ); /* this is shape 15 */
  gdImageSetThickness( gdImage, 4 );

  gdImageLine ( gdImage, 100, 200, 200, 200, blue);

  jpgFile = fopen( "test.jpg", "wb" );
  gdImageJpeg( gdImage, jpgFile, -1 );

  fclose( jpgFile );
  gdImageDestroy( gdImage );
}
```

It would be great if you could help, thanks :)